# XSLT - variable in condition is not assigned with array value

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon-js

Using xslt3 (Saxon JS) and not bound to a specific XSLT version

Given this sample.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>
<tasks>
    <task id="id0"/>
    <task id="id1" parent="#id0" deps="#id2 #id3 #id0"/>
    <task id="id2" parent="#id0"/>
    <task id="id3" parent="#id0"/>
</tasks>
```

and this sample.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tasks/task">
            <xsl:variable name="parentTask" select="replace(@parent,'#','')"/>
            
            <xsl:variable name="depTasks">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@deps">

                        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(replace(@deps,'#',''),'\s')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$parentTask"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <parent id="{@id}">
                <xsl:for-each select="/tasks/task[@id=$depTasks]">
                    <dep>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </dep>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </parent>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would expect the `$depTasks` variable to contain an array (all the *deps* listed in the `deps` attribute) or a single value (the *dep* listed in the `parent` attribute), and obtain a transformation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent id="id0"/>
<parent id="id1">
    <dep>id2</dep>
    <dep>id3</dep>
    <dep>id0</dep>
</parent>
<parent id="id2">
    <dep>id0</dep>
</parent>
<parent id="id3">
    <dep>id0</dep>
</parent>
```

BUT instead I'm getting this result (it seems that only the first element of the tokenization is assigned)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent id="id0"/>
<parent id="id1">
    <dep>id2</dep>
    <!-- MISSING DEPS -->
</parent>
<parent id="id2">
    <dep>id0</dep>
</parent>
<parent id="id3">
    <dep>id0</dep>
</parent>
```

Do problems or limitations exist for variable assigment inside conditions? Or am I missing something here?

Note that, if I change a bit the stylesheet and declare the variable OUTSIDE a condition, an array is assigned as I expect.

sample2.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tasks/task">
            <xsl:variable name="parentTask" select="replace(@parent,'#','')"/>
            <!-- VARIABLE assignement outside a condition: value is an array -->
            <xsl:variable name="depTasks" select="tokenize(replace(@deps,'#',''),'\s')"/>

            <parent id="{@id}">
                <xsl:for-each select="/tasks/task[@id=$depTasks]">
                    <dep>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </dep>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </parent>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resulting in this transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent id="id0"/>
<parent id="id1">
    <dep>id0</dep>
    <dep>id2</dep>
    <dep>id3</dep>
</parent>
<parent id="id2"/>
<parent id="id3"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not using any arrays in your code at all. In

```
      <xsl:variable name="depTasks">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@deps">

                    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(replace(@deps,'#',''),'\s')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$parentTask"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
```

you are creating a result tree fragment containing a text node with the string value of the `tokenize` call or the `$parentTask` variable.

In `<xsl:variable name="depTasks" select="tokenize(replace(@deps,'#',''),'\s')"/>` the value of the variable is the result of the `tokenize` call which is a sequence of string values.

If for the previous approach, although not recommeded, you wanted a sequence of string, you would need to use

```
<xsl:variable name="depTasks" as="xs:string*">
  ...
  <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(...)"/>

  ...

</xsl:variable>
```

The preferred way for the more complex part would be `select="if (@deps) then tokenize(...) else $parentTask"`.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Why don't you recommend the approach above? Is there a more idiomatic or correct solution?

Comment: @FedericoDestefanis, any place where you can use `<xsl:variable name="variable-name" select="expression-to-select-or-compute-variable-value"/>` is the better, easier, shorter, usually more efficient approach than trying to create variable values with the content constructor inside of `xsl:variable`. That can and should be done if you create new nodes but in my view not for selecting sequences of strings as the result of a simple and single function call like `tokenize`, that simply "belongs" into the `select` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Martin Honnen's answer:

If you are using XSLT 3.0, do not declare your stylesheet as `version="1.0"`. Doing so invokes backwards-compatible behavior which can significantly alter your result.

For example, the `xsl:value` instruction (which you are using in several places) will output the string-value of only the first node of the selected sequence, instead of all of them.